# Update one item inside JSON object instead of writing whole file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently learning Node.js, at the moment I have a JSON file (called cars.json) which is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "brand": "BMW",
    "bookedUntil": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "brand": "Mercedes",
    "bookedUntil": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "brand": "Golf",
    "bookedUntil": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "brand": "Holden",
    "bookedUntil": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "brand": "Subaru",
    "bookedUntil": null
  }
]
```

I have a `PUT` method which gets passed an ID value, this ID value is associated with an item inside the JSON object.

The method is as follows:

```
const data = require('./public/cars.json'); // JSON FILE

app.put('/booking/:id', (req, res) => {
    data.forEach((car) => {
        if (car.id == req.params.id) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            car.bookedUntil = date;
        }
    })

    fs.writeFile('./public/cars.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (error) => {
        if (error) {

        } else {
            res.send('Booking has been made');
        }
    });
});
```

All I am doing is finding the record that matches the ID, updating the `bookedUntil` field with a date in the future i.e one day then re-writing the file back to disk.

Now this is working as expected, however I'm curious to find out if I can just update one item without having to loop and re-write the whole file again?

Comment: No, JSON files don’t really work for in-place updates. You can do that with a database, though, like PostgreSQL or SQLite. Or put each car in a different file! The filesystem is a kind of database \o/

Comment: You shouldn't `require` `JSON`. But instead read as file then `JSON.parse` it.